# Find Average of a node in Multiple JSON strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, average

I have searched through many topics, find some relevant answers too, but I am still not able to reach to a solution, hence I am posting this question.

**Problem Description**

```
EmployeeResponse1 = [{"Ques":"1","Rating":"7"},{"Ques":"2","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"3","Rating":"6"},{"Ques":"4","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"5","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"6","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"7","Rating":"7"},{"Ques":"8","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"9","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"10","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"11","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"12","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"13","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"14","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"15","Rating":"1"},{"Ques":"16","Rating":"10"}]

EmployeeResponse2 = [{"Ques":"1","Rating":"5"},{"Ques":"2","Rating":"4"},{"Ques":"3","Rating":"7"},{"Ques":"4","Rating":"8"},{"Ques":"5","Rating":"5"},{"Ques":"6","Rating":"9"},{"Ques":"7","Rating":"10"},{"Ques":"8","Rating":"4"},{"Ques":"9","Rating":"9"},{"Ques":"10","Rating":"6"},{"Ques":"11","Rating":"6"},{"Ques":"12","Rating":"6"},{"Ques":"13","Rating":"7"},{"Ques":"14","Rating":"7"},{"Ques":"15","Rating":"9"},{"Ques":"16","Rating":"8"}]
```

I have these two JSON strings in c# (there can be more).. Now I want to make a final JSON string which will be like:

```
EmployeeResponseAvg = [{"Ques":"1","Rating":"6"},{"Ques":"2","Rating":"2.5"},{"Ques":"3","Rating":"6.5"},{"Ques":"4","Rating":"4.5"},{"Ques":"5","Rating":"3"},{"Ques":"6","Rating":"5"},{"Ques":"7","Rating":"8.5"},{"Ques":"8","Rating":"2.5"},....,{"Ques":"16", "Rating": "9"}]
```

like I want rating of Ques = 1 should be the average of Rating (Ques = 1 of string 1) and Rating (Ques = 1 of string 2)... similarly for other questions

i.e like FINAL =[{ QUES = 1, RATING = (Emp1(Rating.WHERE(QUES = 1), Emp2(Rating.WHERE(QUES = 1),).AVERAGE),....................}]

**Work So Far**

*MODEL -> SurveyResponse.cs*

```
public class SurveyResponse
{
    public string Ques { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseDataCalls
{
    public static SurveyResponse PutData(string t, string v)
    {
        SurveyResponse s = new SurveyResponse();
        s.Ques = t;
        s.Rating = v;
        return s;
    }
}
```

---

*WebAPI RevGroupChartController.cs*

```
public class RevGroupChartController : ApiController
{
    private hr_toolEntities _db = new hr_toolEntities();

    public object Get(int cid, int gid)
    {

        spiderChart obj = new spiderChart();

        var group_employees = (from ge in _db.hrt_group_employee
                               where ge.fk_group_id == gid
                               select ge.fk_employee_id).ToList();

        List<string> EMP = new List<string>();
        List<string> SUP = new List<string>();

        List<SurveyResponse> EmpResponse = new List<SurveyResponse>();
        List<SurveyResponse> SupResponse = new List<SurveyResponse>();

        List<List<SurveyResponse>> tmpEMP = new List<List<SurveyResponse>>();
        List<List<SurveyResponse>> tmpSUP = new List<List<SurveyResponse>>();

        foreach(var emp in group_employees)
        {
            int eid = Convert.ToInt32(emp);
            var Data = (from d in _db.hrt_cycle_response
                        join g in _db.hrt_cycle_groups on d.hrt_cycle.pk_cycle_id equals g.fk_cycle_id
                        where d.fk_cycle_id == cid && g.fk_group_id == gid && d.fk_employee_id == eid
                        select new
                        {
                            d.response_employee_answers,
                            d.response_supervisor_answers
                        }).First();
            EMP.Add(Data.response_employee_answers);
            SUP.Add(Data.response_supervisor_answers);
        }

        foreach(var e in EMP)
        {
            //tmpEMP = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TEMP>(e);
            var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<SurveyResponse> em = s.Deserialize<List<SurveyResponse>>(e);
            tmpEMP.Add(em);

        }
        foreach (var s in SUP)
        {
            //tmpSUP = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TEMP>(s);
            var e = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<SurveyResponse> sp = e.Deserialize<List<SurveyResponse>>(s);
            tmpSUP.Add(sp);
        }
        var empl = _db.hrt_questions.Select(x => new { x.question_name }).ToList();

        List<int[]> Emprating = new List<int[]>();
        //int avgRating;
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach(var item in tmpSUP)
        {
            int noofQ = item.Count;
            int[] i = new int[noofQ];
            for (int y = 0; y > tmpSUP.Count; y++)
            {
                i[y] = Convert.ToInt32(item[cnt].Rating);
            }
            Emprating.Add(i);
            cnt++;
        }

        //obj.Employee = Data.response_employee_answers;
        //obj.Supervisor = Data.response_supervisor_answers;
        obj.ques = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < empl.Count; i++)
        {
            obj.ques.Add(empl[i].question_name);
        }

        return obj;

    }

    public class TEMP
    {
        public List<SurveyResponse> data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation of Code**

I pass a cycle ID and a group ID...
Each group has more than 1 employee and each employee has a supervisor
so if say group ID 1023 has 2 employees.
Now we have 2 employees and 2 supervisors
we have a json record for each of them

```
LIKE DB TABLE RESPONSE {fk_emp_id, fk_sup_id, cycle_id, emp_reponse(json), supervisor_response(json)}
```

so I need to make ONE JSON string for employees (which contains the average of all ratings)
and ONE JSON string for SUPERVISOR (again, average of both the JSONs)
there could be any number of employees, depending on the group size
and each employee will always have a supervisor

In short I want a a string like:

```
FinalEmployeeResponse = [{'Ques': '1', 'Rating': 'R1'}, {'Ques': '2', 'Rating': 'R2'}, {'Ques': '3', 'Rating': 'R3'}, {'Ques': '4', 'Rating': 'R4'}, ........, {'Ques': '16', 'Rating': 'R16'}]
```

Here, `R1 = AVERAGE(Emp1json.Rating.WHERE('Ques' = 1), Emp2json.Rating.WHERE('Ques' = 1), .....)`
and

```
R2 = AVERAGE(Emp1json.Rating.WHERE('Ques' = 2), Emp2json.Rating.WHERE('Ques' = 2), .....)
```

... and so on....

Looking forward to your responses.

I am new on stack overflow, please ask for more details if I have missed something.

Comment: If there is any other simpler way, that is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 1 line answer to this using LINQ.

```
double _avg1 = tmpEMP.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ElementAt(i).Rating)).Average();
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to parse this as JSON. The quick and dirty way is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json1 = @"[{""Ques"":""1"",""Rating"":""7""},{""Ques"":""2"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""3"",""Rating"":""6""},{""Ques"":""4"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""5"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""6"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""7"",""Rating"":""7""},{""Ques"":""8"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""9"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""10"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""11"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""12"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""13"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""14"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""15"",""Rating"":""1""},{""Ques"":""16"",""Rating"":""10""}]";
        string json2 = @"[{""Ques"":""1"",""Rating"":""5""},{""Ques"":""2"",""Rating"":""4""},{""Ques"":""3"",""Rating"":""7""},{""Ques"":""4"",""Rating"":""8""},{""Ques"":""5"",""Rating"":""5""},{""Ques"":""6"",""Rating"":""9""},{""Ques"":""7"",""Rating"":""10""},{""Ques"":""8"",""Rating"":""4""},{""Ques"":""9"",""Rating"":""9""},{""Ques"":""10"",""Rating"":""6""},{""Ques"":""11"",""Rating"":""6""},{""Ques"":""12"",""Rating"":""6""},{""Ques"":""13"",""Rating"":""7""},{""Ques"":""14"",""Rating"":""7""},{""Ques"":""15"",""Rating"":""9""},{""Ques"":""16"",""Rating"":""8""}]";
        string averages = AverageNodes(json1, json2);

        Console.WriteLine(averages);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string AverageNodes(params string[] json)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(""Ques"":""(?<question>\d+)"",""Rating"":""(?<rating>\d+)"")", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var ANUs = regex.Matches(string.Join("", json))
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => new { Question = m.Groups["question"].Value, Rating = int.Parse(m.Groups["rating"].Value) })
            .GroupBy(a => a.Question, a => a.Rating)
            .Select(a => string.Format("{{\"Ques\":\"{0}\",\"Rating\":\"{1}\"}}", a.Key, a.Average()));

        return "[" + string.Join(",", ANUs) + "]";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just found an easier answer.

Loop through no. of ques, i and double _avg1 = tmpEMP.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ElementAt(i).Rating)).Average();